# JQuery load with animation/transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading `div` on click with jQuery load method, its working fine but I wanted to add animation like slideUp/slideDown effect, but not sure how to achieve this:

following is the code

```
$('.search_bar > input').click(function(){
        $("#search_layer").load("file-url.html");
        $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden", "height": "auto"});
});
```

Can anyone please suggest how to add slideUp/Down transition, I tried CSS transition as well but no luck

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.load(url, callback)` to do stuff after element is loaded. First set it's `display: none` via css, than do

```
$('#search_layer').load(
    'file-url.html',
    function () {
        $('#search_layer .div-to-show').slideDown();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.search_bar > input').click(function(){
        $("#search_layer").load("file-url.html");
$("#search_layer").slideToggle();
        $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden", "height": "auto"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)

for example

> $(document).on("click", ".search_bar > input", function () {
>       $(this).velocity("transition.whirlOut", {
>           stagger: 1000,
>           duration: 1000,
>           complete: function () {
>               //on complete...
>           }
>       });
>   });

Answer (score 0):

you can add a callback function in the load method, and then animate it in the callback :

```
$('.search_bar > input').click(function(){
        $("#search_layer").load("file-url.html",'', animateContent());
        $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden", "height": "auto"});
});

function animateContent() {
        $("#search_layer").animate({
        left: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but the answer provided by @Justinas is easy to use and using the same callback function